# How would I separate two strings that can contain any character?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am getting n strings that contain any character. I want them to write to a file in such a way that they can be parsed and separated. The customer can write anything in the string and it should not break the parse logic. Separating using random strings and timestamp etc would break.

Comment: In what language?  What code have you tried using?  What result are you getting?

Comment: @SeeDerekEngineer I am using Java. I tried separating by appending some random string or timestamp, but if customer writes the future timestamp, it would break the parsing logic.

Comment: The answer is right there in your own tags. Java Object Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Consider serializing to and deserializing from a standard serialization format. I would suggest using [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

```
// using the JSONUtil library
// read the strings into the `myStrings` array
String[] myStrings = ...
String json = JSONUtil.toJSON(myStrings);
```

It can the be parsed quite simply:

```
// read the contents of the file into the `json` variable
String json = ...
Object data = JSONParser.parseJSON(json);
```

(I chose the JSONUtil library arbitrarily; there are a number of JSON serializing/deserializing libraries on the [JSON page](http://www.json.org/).)

(Disclaimer: I have absolutely no experience programming in Java.)